# How can I find path of AWS CLI in windows

Tags: aws-cli

I have successfully installed aws cli, but I'm getting
"'aws' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I think it is problem with the path settings. How do I know the path of AWSCLI for windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, it should be configured with the installation.

Please try the following.

On my system for version
[image]

The path entry is

```
C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\
```

Check that this path "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2" exists on your system. If it's nonexistent then search for aws.exe in C:\Program Files. The folder in which aws.exe is present will be your base path. If you don't find the aws.exe do a re-install.

If the path "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2" exists on your system. Or there is some other folder in which aws.exe is present then that path needs to be configured manually.

Set the path manually. by following steps.

**Steps to add this entry in a path environment variable.**

1. Click on windows and search edit environment.

[image]

2. In the System variable section click on the path.

[image]

3. Add the path "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2"

[image]

4. Save. Open a new command line and type aws.